# Why isn't the eigenclass equivalent to self.class, when it looks so similar?

Tags: ruby, language-features, eigenclass

I've missed the memo somewhere, and I hope you'll explain this to me.

Why is the eigenclass of an object different from `self.class`?

```
class Foo
  def initialize(symbol)
    eigenclass = class << self
      self
    end
    eigenclass.class_eval do
      attr_accessor symbol
    end
  end
end
```

My train of logic that equates the eigenclass with `class.self` is rather simple:

`class << self` is a way of declaring class methods, rather than instance methods. It's a shortcut to `def Foo.bar`.

So within the reference to the class object, returning `self` should be identical to `self.class`. This is because `class << self` would set `self` to `Foo.class` for definition of class methods/attributes.

Am I just confused? Or, is this a sneaky trick of Ruby meta-programming?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`class << self` is more than just a way of declaring class methods (though it can be used that way).  Probably you've seen some usage like:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def a
      print "I could also have been defined as def Foo.a."
    end
  end
end
```

This works, and is equivalent to `def Foo.a`, but the way it works is a little subtle.  The secret is that `self`, in that context, refers to the object `Foo`, whose class is a unique, anonymous subclass of `Class`.  This subclass is called `Foo`'s *eigenclass*.  So `def a` creates a new method called `a` in `Foo`'s eigenclass, accessible by the normal method call syntax: `Foo.a`.

Now let's look at a different example:

```
str = "abc"
other_str = "def"

class << str
  def frob
    return self + "d"
  end
end

print str.frob # => "abcd"
print other_str.frob # => raises an exception, 'frob' is not defined on other_str
```

This example is the same as the last one, though it may be hard to tell at first.  `frob` is defined, not on the `String` class, but on the eigenclass of `str`, a unique anonymous subclass of `String`.  So `str` has a `frob` method, but instances of `String` in general do not.  We could also have overridden methods of String (very useful in certain tricky testing scenarios).

Now we're equipped to understand your original example.  Inside `Foo`'s initialize method, `self` refers not to the class `Foo`, but to some particular *instance* of `Foo`.  Its eigenclass is a subclass of `Foo`, but it is not `Foo`; it couldn't be, or else the trick we saw in the second example couldn't work.  So to continue your example:

```
f1 = Foo.new(:weasels)
f2 = Foo.new(:monkeys)

f1.weasels = 4 # Fine
f2.monkeys = 5 # Also ok
print(f1.monkeys) # Doesn't work, f1 doesn't have a 'monkeys' method.
```

Comment: So then, each instance is an anonymous subclass of the created class?

Comment: Each instance's *class* is an anonymous subclass of the created class.  f1's class is anonymous subclass of Foo, Foo's class is an anonymous subclass of Class.

Comment: nice answer :) a lot of people do not understand this as clearly as you do.

Comment: so f1's class is NOT Foo, but rather an anonymous sub-class of Foo? But, when I call a method on f1, doesn't it look in Foo to find that method? or Does it look in the anonymous sub-class of Foo and then in Foo?

Comment: @berto77 exactly, it's the same as any other subclass relationship.  First it looks in the eigenclass, then it looks in Foo, then it looks in Foo's superclasses if any.  Or, conceptually that's how it works; the implementation  has some optimizations for the common case, IIRC.

Comment: How is the eigenclass of f1 different then, conceptually, from the actual instance of f1. If f1 is the only instance that will ever have access to the methods of its eigenclass, doesn't the distinction between f1 and its eigenclass kind of break down?

Comment: @elju Yeah, kinda.  The really important distinction is between "Foo" and "f1's eigenclass"; if you've got that, you're probably fine.

Answer (score 50):

The simplest answer: the eigenclass can't be instantiated.

```
class F
 def eigen
  class << self 
   self
  end
 end
end
F.new.eigen.new #=> TypeError: can't create instance of virtual class
```

Comment: you may have only 1 point on this website, but i like you and your style.

Comment: Agree w/ banister; this is a great answer

Comment: This is an extremely insightful and helpful comment IFF one has already read @DavidSeiler's answer above.

Comment: Theo power here is demo'ing the exception that is raised.

Answer (score 11):

Yehuda Katz does a pretty good job of explaining the subtleties in "[Metaprogramming in Ruby: It's All About the Self](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/)"

Comment: subtitles or... subtleties? ;)