# Rails class << self

Tags: ruby, class

I would like to understand what `class << self` stands for in the next example.

```
module Utility
  class Options #:nodoc:
    class << self
      def parse(args)          
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @xpepermint, you should probably add the `ruby` tag to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [class << self idiom in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### this

```
module Utility
  class Options #:nodoc:
    class << self
      # we are inside Options's singleton class
      def parse(args)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

### is equivalent to:

```
module Utility
  class Options #:nodoc:
    def Options.parse(args)

    end
  end
end
```

### A couple examples to help you understand :

```
class A
  HELLO = 'world'
  def self.foo
    puts "class method A::foo, HELLO #{HELLO}"
  end

  def A.bar
    puts "class method A::bar, HELLO #{HELLO}"
  end

  class << self
    HELLO = 'universe'
    def zim
      puts "class method A::zim, HELLO #{HELLO}"
    end
  end

end
A.foo
A.bar
A.zim
puts "A::HELLO #{A::HELLO}"

# Output
# class method A::foo, HELLO world
# class method A::bar, HELLO world
# class method A::zim, HELLO universe
# A::HELLO world
```

Comment: same as def self,parse(args) ?

Comment: @xpepermint, `self.parse(args)`, yes. (not `,`)

Comment: Is this still true for the current version of ruby?

Answer (score 4):

This is an eigenclass. This question's [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar).

Comment: @Frank Shearar, out of fairness, I'm guessing the @xpepermint didn't realize this was an eigenclass :)

Comment: Now official called singleton_class: http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L166