# Ruby, get hours, seconds and time from Date.day_fraction_to_time

Tags: ruby, datetime, comparison, method-missing

I've found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679266/can-ruby-print-out-time-difference-duration-readily/1679305#1679305).

```
  start = DateTime.now
  sleep 15
  stop = DateTime.now
  #minutes
  puts ((stop-start) * 24 * 60).to_i

  hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.day_fraction_to_time(stop-start)
```

I have the following error:

```
`<main>': private method `day_fraction_to_time' called for Date:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've checked */usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb* and I've found it:

```
def day_fraction_to_time(fr) # :nodoc:
  ss,  fr = fr.divmod(SECONDS_IN_DAY) # 4p
  h,   ss = ss.divmod(3600)
  min, s  = ss.divmod(60)
  return h, min, s, fr * 86400
end
```

But I have no problem if I run it with ruby1.8. */usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb* gives me:

```
  def self.day_fraction_to_time(fr)
    ss,  fr = fr.divmod(SECONDS_IN_DAY) # 4p
    h,   ss = ss.divmod(3600)
    min, s  = ss.divmod(60)
    return h, min, s, fr
  end
```

So i went to see the [documentation(1.9)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Date.html) and there's no trace of this method. I know it's a dumb question, but why did they remove it? There is even this example on how to use the method in */usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb*:

```
 def secs_to_new_year(now = DateTime::now())
     new_year = DateTime.new(now.year + 1, 1, 1)
     dif = new_year - now
     hours, mins, secs, ignore_fractions = Date::day_fraction_to_time(dif)
     return hours * 60 * 60 + mins * 60 + secs
 end
```

but I'm still getting the error:

```
test.rb:24:in `secs_to_new_year': private method `day_fraction_to_time' called for Date:Class (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it was made private, but you can still access it:

```
hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.send(:day_fraction_to_time, stop-start)
```

This way you override the OOP encapsulation mechanizm... This is not a very nice thing to do, but it works.

Comment: Exactly. I'm breaking the OOP structure, so annoying. Isn't it `__send__` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found another method which seems more elegant to me:

```
start = DateTime.now
sleep 3
stop = DateTime.now

puts "Date.day_fraction_to_time using wrapper"
class Date
    class << self
      def wrap_day_fraction_to_time( day_frac )
        day_fraction_to_time( day_frac )
      end
   end
end
hours, minutes, seconds, frac =
    Date.wrap_day_fraction_to_time( stop - start )
p hours, minutes, seconds, frac
```

Thanks to Colin Bartlett from [ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217068#942032)

To understand how it works I suggest to read David Seiler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar)

Comment: This is more elegant in fact, in some way, but on the other hand - monkey patching builtin classes is also a thing which is seen as "bad practise"...

Comment: yep, but right now I'm out of ideas. I mean I can of course write a function ex novo but it annoys me that a method is available and I can't use it.