# Ruby class inheritance: What is `<<` (double less than)?

Tags: ruby

```
class << Awesomeness
```

What is this `<<` for? I searched, but the results only tell me about string concatenation...

Answer (score 141, accepted):

While it's true that `class << something` is the syntax for a singleton class, as someone else said, it's most often used to define class methods within a class definition. But these two usages are consistent. Here's how.

Ruby lets you add methods to any particular instance by doing this:

```
class << someinstance
  def foo
    "Hello."
  end
end
```

This adds a method `foo` to someinstance, not to its class but to that one particular instance. (Actually, foo is added to the instance's "singleton class," but that's more or less an implementation quirk.) After the above code executes, you can send method foo to someinstance:

```
someinstance.foo   => "Hello."
```

but you can't send foo to other instances of the same class. That's what `<<` is nominally for. But people more commonly use this feature for syntactic gymnastics like this:

```
class Thing
  def do_something
  end

  class << self
    def foo
      puts "I am #{self}"
    end
  end
end
```

When this code -- this class definition -- executes, what is `self`? It's the class `Thing`. Which means `class << self` is the same as saying "add the following methods to class Thing." That is, foo is a class method. After the above completes, you can do this:

```
t = Thing.new
t.do_something  => does something
t.class.foo     => "I am Thing"
t.foo           => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'
```

And when you think about what `<<` is doing, it all makes sense. It's a way to append to a particular instance, and in the common case, the instance being appended to is a class, so the methods within the block become class methods.

In short, it's a terse way to create class methods within a class definition block. Another way would be to do this:

```
class Thing
  def self.foo
    # ...
  end
end
```

Same thing. Your example is actually a syntax error, but if you understand how `<<` is used with instances and the class keyword, you'll know how to correct it.

Comment: Interesting! Is such method any useful in every-day programming?

Comment: @Omega: Yea, you would see this, for instance, when you have more than one method that you want to make a class method, and you don't want to have to prefix them all with "self.".  You can just put them all in that block and not worry about it.

Comment: The last bit made it all click. Also note that `class << self` works in the sense that even though `Thing` is a class, it's also just an instance of its superclass. So there's nothing special about classes vs instances. Every class in ruby is an instance of its superclass (except for BasicObject).

Answer (score 22):

`<<` is the syntax for ["Singleton class definition"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#scdef). [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar) of where/how it is "typically" used.

In `a = "abc"; a << "xyz"` it is the syntax for "appending data" (to string, array etc.)

Comment: It is used in this manner [extracted from nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb): simple_form_for(*(args << options), &block) << after_nested_form_callbacks

Comment: In Ruby `<<` is called the `shovel operator`

Answer (score 20):

If you want inheritance (based on your question title), you want a single `<`:

```
class Awesome < ParentAwesomeness
```

The code you provide isn't valid ruby:

```
class Awesomeness
end

class Awesome << Awesomeness
end

SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n'
```

Comment: GREAT to know. Hard to find this factoid when searching.

Comment: funny how few people looked at the title.  The other explanations are great, but kind of missed what the asker was looking for.