# What does << mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, operators

I have code:

```
  def make_all_thumbs(source)
    sizes = ['1000','1100','1200','800','600']
    threads = []
    sizes.each do |s|
      threads << Thread.new(s) {
        create_thumbnail(source+'.png', source+'-'+s+'.png', s)
      }
    end
  end
```

what does `<<` mean?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

It can have 3 distinct meanings:

**'<<' as an ordinary method**

In most cases '<<' is a method defined like the rest of them, in your case it means "add to the end of this array" (see also [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000225)).

That's in your particular case, but there are also a lot of other occasions where you'll encounter the "<<" method. I won't call it 'operator' since it's really a method that is defined on some object that can be overridden by you or implemented for your own objects. Other cases of '<<'

- String concatenation:  "a" << "b"
- Writing output to an IO: io << "A line of text\n"
- Writing data to a message digest, HMAC or cipher: sha << "Text to be hashed"
- left-shifting of an OpenSSL::BN: bn << 2
- ...

---

**Singleton class definition**

Then there is the mysterious shift of the current scope (=change of self) within the program flow:

```
class A
  class << self
    puts self # self is the singleton class of A
  end
end

a = A.new
class << a
  puts self # now it's the singleton class of object a
end
```

The mystery `class << self` made me wonder and investigate about the internals there. Whereas in all the examples I mentioned `<<` is really a method defined in a class, i.e.

```
obj << stuff
```

is equivalent to

```
obj.<<(stuff)
```

the `class << self` (or any object in place of self) construct is truly different. It is really a builtin feature of the language itself, in CRuby it's defined in *parse.y* as

```
k_class tLSHFT expr
```

`k_class` is the 'class' keyword, where `tLSHFT` is a '<<' token and `expr` is an arbitrary expression. That is, you can actually write

```
class << <any expression>
```

and will get *shifted* into the singleton class of the result of the expression. The `tLSHFT` sequence will be parsed as a 'NODE_SCLASS' expression, which is called a *Singleton Class definition* (cf. node.c)

```
case NODE_SCLASS:
    ANN("singleton class definition");
    ANN("format: class << [nd_recv]; [nd_body]; end");
    ANN("example: class << obj; ..; end");
    F_NODE(nd_recv, "receiver");
    LAST_NODE;
    F_NODE(nd_body, "singleton class definition");
    break;
```

---

**Here Documents**

*Here Documents* use '<<' in a way that is again totally different. You can define a string that spans over multiple lines conveniently by declaring

```
here_doc = <<_EOS_
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
...
_EOS_
```

To distinguish the 'here doc operator' an arbitrary String delimiter has to immediately follow the '<<'. Everything inbetween that initial delimiter and the second occurrence of that same delimiter will be part of the final string. It is also possible to use '<<-', the difference is that using the latter will ignore any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Might confuse beginners, but as a wise man (might've) said, "ask a broad question, get a thorough answer".

Comment: Hi thank you @emboss: so << is the equivalent of calling the push method on an array?

Comment: This is one of the most thorough but still focus on topic answer I red on stackoverflow I think. I especially appreciated how you gave the information of what the esoteric identifiers meant. This culture of cryptic names widely spread in our industry is just throwing more hindrances at topics already hard enough to grasp by themselves. 

Answer (score 36):

Mostly used in arrays to append the value to the end of the array.

```
a = ["orange"]
a << "apple"
puts a
```

gives this

```
  ["orange", "apple"]
```

result.

Comment: One more use of `<<` is in [class inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182628/ruby-class-inheritance-what-is-double-less-than)

Answer (score 10):

'a << b' means append b to the end of a

Answer (score 7):

It's the operator which allows you to feed **existing** arrays, by **appending** new items.

In the example above you are just populating the empty array `threads` with 5 new threads.

Answer (score 7):

In ruby you always have more the one way to do things. So, Ruby has some nice shortcuts for common method names. like this one is for .push instead of typing out the .push method name, you can simply use <<, the concatenation operator. in fact in some cases you can use any of these for the same operation .push and + with <<.

Like you can see in this example:

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]
alphabet << "d" # Update me!
alphabet.push("e") # Update me!
print alphabet 
caption = "the boy is surrounded by "
caption << "weezards!" # Me, too!
caption += " and more. " # Me, too!
# .push can no be uses for concatenate 
print caption
```

so you see the result is:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
the boy is surrounded by weezards! and more.
```

you can use the operator << to push a element into an array or to concatenate a string to another.

so, what this is this doing is creating a new element/object Thread type and pushing it into the array.

```
 threads << Thread.new(s) {
        create_thumbnail(source+'.png', source+'-'+s+'.png', s)
      }
```

Answer (score 7):

In ruby '<<' operator is basically used for:

1. Appending a value in the array (at last position)

   [2, 4, 6] << 8
   It will give [2, 4, 6, 8]
2. It also used for some active record operations in ruby. For example we have a Cart and LineItem model associated as cart has_many line_items. Cart.find(A).line_items will return ActiveRecord::Associations object with line items that belongs to cart 'A'.

Now, to add (or say to associate) another line_item (X) to cart (A),

```
Cart.find(A).line_items << LineItem.find(X)
```

3. Now to add another LineItem to the same cart 'A', but this time we will not going to create any line_item object (I mean will not create activerecord object manually)

   Cart.find(A).line_items << LineItem.new

In above code << will save object and append it to left side active record association array.

And many others which are already covered in above answers.

Answer (score 2):

Also, since Ruby 2.6, the `<<` method is defined also on `Proc`.

[Proc#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html#method-i-3C-3C) allows to compose two or more procs.

Answer (score 1):

It means add to the end (append).

```
a = [1,2,3]
a << 4
a = [1,2,3,4]
```