# About "<<" operator in this Rails association case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails. 
In a Rails application, I saw some code like following:

In **model**, there is a class `Car`:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

In **controller**, there is a method "**some_method**"

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

   def some_method
      @my_car = Car.new()

      #What does the following code do? 
      #What does "<<" mean here?
      @my_car.components << Component.new()
   end


end
```

I got three questions to ask:

**1.** In the code in controller `@my_car.components << Component.new()` , what does it do? What `<<` means ?

**2.** Are there any other usages of "<<" in Ruby-On-Rails or in Ruby ?

**3.** Does `Car` class must explicitly define the `has_many` association with `Component` class if "**<<**" is used Or is the "**<<**" can be used to add a new association to `Car`, even the association is not defined in `Car` class explicitly?

Comment: You can use << also with a string. `"something " << "other"` results in `"something other". You can overload the << operator in any class, just like in C++. Also, note that it's just one `<` in the model, and it signify inheritance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After your edit:

**Point 1**

```
@my_car.components << Component.new()
```

is the same as

```
@my_car.components.push(Component.new())
```

**Point 2**

It lets you add items to a collection or even concatenate strings.

Some links:

- [for arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)
- [for strings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)
- [for io streams](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-i-3C-3C)

notice you can naturally overload or define your own.

**Point 3**

Relationships must be explicit, otherwise Rails can't create the adequate methods: `@my_car.components` wouldn't have any sense.

Comment: Does it also hint that the Car object is associated with Component object with "has_many" association (Car has_many Component)?

Comment: @ apneadiving , sorry for the late acceptance, your answer is excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 1. & 2., I summarized the different meanings of `<<` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852072/what-does-mean-in-ruby/6852104#6852104).

Answer (score 0):

<< adds an item to an array.

So in the example above you are adding a new component to the Car.components array. It's part of Ruby and you'll see it used often.

Comment: Does Car class must explicitly define the has_many association with Component class or the "<<" can be used to add a new association?

Comment: @Mellon: it must explicitly define the relationship

Comment: apneadiving is correct, you must have a has_many relationship defined.