# ActiveRecord how to add existing record to association in has_many :through relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, rails-admin

In my rails project I have three models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_categorizations
  has_many :category, :through => :recipe_categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_categories, allow_destroy: :true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_categorizations
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_categorizations
end

class RecipeCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :category
end
```

With this simple has_many :through setup, how can I take a given recipe like so:

```
@recipe = Recipe.first
```

and add a category to this recipe based off an existing category, and have it be updated on the respective category as well.

So:

```
@category = #Existing category here
@recipe.categories.build(@category)
```

and then

```
@category.recipes
```

will contain @recipe?

The reason why I ask this is because I'm trying to achieve this behavior through the gem rails_admin, and every time I create a new recipe object, the form to specify it's categories is the form to create a new category, rather than attach an existing one to this recipe.

So it would be helpful to understand how ActiveRecord associates existing records to newly created records in a many_to_many relationship.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [build](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/build) method is close enough to the `new` method, used to create new records.

if you need to add a current `category` to `@recipe.categories`, you just need to:

```
@recipe.categories << @category
```

This will add a record in the `RecipeCategorization` table (automatically saving it).

now `@category.recipes` will include `@recipe`

Comment: Thanks! Isnt << the bitshift operator?

Comment: Check it out [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

Comment: @AdamBronfin not really. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852072/what-does-mean-in-ruby

Comment: The shovel operator no longer works in Rails 5. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25906