# What does <<- mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
  template = <<-TPL.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
    ╭───────╮
    | X X X |
    | X X X |
    | X YYX |
    | X X X |
    ╰───────╯
  TPL
```

This is a snippet from `gem rubycards`.

I understand that it is storing some string in template. But what does `<<-` do?

Comment: This feature is called here doc. It's a way to define multiline strings. The result contains all **lines** between `<<-TPL` and `TPL`. `gsub(/^\s+/,'')` is applied to this string.

Comment: @Jordan: What's the difference between `duplicate` and `that solved my problem` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents):

> If you are writing a large block of text you may use a “here document”
>   or “heredoc”:
>
> ```
> expected_result = <<HEREDOC
>
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
> HEREDOC
> ```
>
> The heredoc starts on the line following << HEREDOC and ends with the
>   next line that starts with HEREDOC. The result includes the ending
>   newline.
>
> You may use any identifier with a heredoc, but all-uppercase
>   identifiers are typically used.
>
> You may indent the ending identifier if you place a “-” after <<:
>
> ```
>   expected_result = <<-INDENTED_HEREDOC
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
>   INDENTED_HEREDOC
> ```
>
> Note that the while the closing identifier may be indented, the
>   content is always treated as if it is flush left. If you indent the
>   content those spaces will appear in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are many uses for the `<<` operator in Ruby. However, in your specific case the `<<` is used for declaring a string that spans multiple lines. Which allows you to get the matrix looking standard output.

[What does << mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852072/what-does-mean-in-ruby) is a link that has many others

Comment: question is about `<<-`, not `<<` :)

Comment: sorry, TPL wasn't indented so I assumed he didn't even want to know what the - was for.