# About class definition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, metaclass, eigenclass

Recently, I was investigating into some details about classes in Ruby, and was confused by class definition.

In Ruby, the class definition is as follows,

```
class A
    def self.my_method
    end
end
```

and it's the same as

```
class A
    class << self
        def my_method
        end
    end
end
```

then I was confused. For the 1st case, self can be regarded as a pointer to currently using object, and current class of the context is A. And the method looking-up is done recursively. But my question is, what does **def** do? How does it change the current object and context? The problem is same for the 2nd case. How does the description like **class << self** change the current object and context?

And another question. As far as I know, all Class objects are obeying design patterns like fly-weight, since they share the same Class object with same definition. Then the eigenclass became confusing. Since the def in a eigenclass actually defines a method with Class object, how can it be related to "def self.*"?

It looks too complicated from the outside, and I may need the design details of Ruby.

Comment: actually i'm not getting your confusion... self is the singleton class instance, so `def self.foobar` declares a class method while `def foobar` declares an instance methods in which self is the current instance.
as for your cases... shouldn't they both be the same? (you are declaring class methods)

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar/1631005#1631005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A
  # self here is A
  def aa
    # self here is the instance of A who called this method
  end
  class << self
    # self is the eigenclass of A, a pseudo-class to store methods to a object.
    # Any object can have an eigenclass.
    def aa
      # self is the pseudo-instance of the eigenclass, self is A.
    end
  end
end
```

This is the same:

```
class A
  def self.aa
  end
end
```

And this:

```
class << A
  def aa
  end
end
```

And also this:

```
def A.aa
end
```

You can open the eigenclass of anything:

```
hello = "hello"
class << hello
  def world
    self << " world"
  end
end
hello.world #=> "hello world"
"my".world  #=> NoMethodError
```

An eigenclass is actually an instance of Class, it has it own eigenclass too.

> "If it appears to be too confusing, just remember that Class is an object and that Object is a class."

Comment: The last sentence inspired me. Thanks!