# What is the class << self in ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't the eigenclass equivalent to self.class, when it looks so similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar)
>   [class << self idiom in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)

I have this class:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_slug

  def remains
    ((end_date - Date.today) + 1).to_i
  end

  def self.url
    "Our_link_#{slug}"
  end

  class << self
    def load_track_lists
      #do somthing 
    end
  end
end
```

and I understand the class and instance methods but the

```
class << self
  def load_track_lists
    #do somthing 
  end
end
```

is really confusing. What is it and how does it differ from the prior two methods?

Comment: @lucapette: Does that look anything like a duplicate? They are similar and related, but not at all duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

The end result is basically the same as if it had been defined as

```
def self.load_track_lists
  #do somthing 
end
```

There are subtle differences between the two methods if you're doing more than just defining methods in the `class << self` block, as described in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630815/why-isnt-the-eigenclass-equivalent-to-self-class-when-it-looks-so-similar), but effectively you're "opening up" the current class to define class level methods in it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't differ from the self.url method. It's basically a container that allows you to put multiple methods without having to put self. in front of  the method name. Probably not useful in the example but can be quite clean for other classes.

IMO it's a developer's preference