# class methods and different styles of programming in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm curious about calling class methods and whether there is any difference between:

```
class Jt
  class << self
    def say_hello
      puts "I want to say hello"
    end
  end
end

class Jt2
  def self.say_hello
    puts "2 want to say hello"
  end
end

Jt.say_hello
Jt2.say_hello
```

Is it just style or is there any difference in how ruby handle these? I always use the latter for Rails stuff but tend to see the former in meta-programming or Rails source code.

Comment: Hmm... so that question + answer seems to be `how?` from a user point of view which I get (I think). I guess I'm just wondering if they are truly equivalent in terms of performance, resources etc... And whether one should be preferred over the other for non-stylistic reasons.

Comment: @sawa This question NOT a duplicate of that other one you linked to.  That question is asking why "eigenclass" is different from "class"; that question is not talking about two different ways to define a method.

Comment: @DavidGrayson You are right. The question that I linked to is related but is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference between those is just style.  They both add a method to the singleton class of the class.  Here is what I did with your code to investigate it:

```
class Jt
  class << self
    def say_hello
      puts "I want to say hello"
    end
  end
end

class Jt2
  def self.say_hello
    puts "2 want to say hello"
  end
end

p Jt.singleton_class.instance_method(:say_hello)   # => #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Jt>#say_hello>
p Jt2.singleton_class.instance_method(:say_hello)  # => #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Jt2>#say_hello>
```

In case it matters, I used JRuby.

Comment: thx, my hunch is you're right and just stylistic. Just getting to know Ruby and would love to see if there was a `deeper` reason as the class method syntax seems ubiquitous in userspace apps while the eigenclass method seems pretty ubiquitous in frameworks, libraries, etc...

Comment: It is not just style. calling `<< self` involves more steps and uses more resource. When you define a method within `<< self`, the same method is defined in two different places. You can notice the difference by using `set_trace_func`.

Comment: thx @sawa , that seems logical but isn't it then surprising that it is the chosen way for writing libraries and frameworks. Not trying to be argumentative just trying to understand.

Comment: @timpone If you care about the resource, the latter way is better. But then, you have to repeat `self.` every time. Using `<< self` is (slightly more) resource consuming, but the programmer does not have to repeat `self.`. That is why some people chose that way.

Comment: thx both to David and @sawa for input. Feel more confident that these are functionally equivalent.

Comment: sawa, do you have any evidence?  Could you show an example of how to use `set_trace_func` so I can understand what you are saying?  What are the "two different places" where the method is defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
class << self
    def say_hello
      puts "I want to say hello"
    end
end
```

- is a `singleton class` inside `class Jt`.

Here is more information[`What's the difference between a class and the singleton of that class in Ruby?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430255/whats-the-difference-between-a-class-and-the-singleton-of-that-class-in-ruby) and Look here
[`Singleton class in Ruby`](http://www.wikyblog.com/AmanKing/Singleton_class_in_Ruby)